# R extract text from image and export it as a CSV

Tags: r, tesseract

Someone just literally provided me with a `screenshot` of a table, and I have to enter the information in `MS-Excel`. I was thinking of finding a way to extract text from this image and export it as a `CSV`.

I did come across  the [tesseract](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html) package, but it doesn't do a good job.

Is there a way to do this in `R`?

Example image:

[image]

Code I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tesseract)

eng = tesseract("eng")
text = tesseract::ocr("path/file_name.png", engine = eng)
cat(text)
```

Comment: When I try it, I would say tesseract does a very good job. I think it gets a little confused by the gridlines, but you could probably process the image a little bit to get rid of them (e.g., see the thresholding options [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imagerExtra/vignettes/gettingstarted.html)), and I bet it would do even better.

Comment: Also the `magick` package has functions for image processing that could help prepare your image for success. I'm not aware of any other high-quality OCR packages in R.

Comment: In case someone is successful with getting rid of the grids of the image, please post here the solution for that. Thanks!

Comment: This will involve finding an OCR package that produces satisfactory results, that's about it. You can play with tesseract settings.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why has the question been voted to close?

Comment: I'm not sure if this could be done cleanly. For example, the string "PRISM_tm" in the `info` column seems to be missing the final stroke of the character "m". Also, the column name of `resolution` and `Date` are almost sticking together, not sure if it's possible to separate them with image processing (also note the final stroke of "n" in column name `resolution` is missing).

Comment: This is an [open issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1979) in tesseract

Comment: The excel versions on iphone and Mac have "Data from Picture": https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture-3c1bb58d-2c59-4bc0-b04a-a671a6868fd7#ID0EAABAAA=iOS/Android

Comment: Google docs is sometimes good for one-offs like this. Try uploading the image to google docs and then open it as a google document. Google will OCR it for you and set it out in a useable form that you could then work with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually worked pretty well. I didn't check the whole thing for errors but at first glance it all looks correct, including "PRISM_tm". The trick is to make the image quite large as tesseract seems to ignore small characters:

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 7.1.0.31
#> Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp, x11
#> Disabled features: fftw, ghostscript
#> Using 12 threads
library(tesseract)
input <- image_read("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxGHc.png") %>% 
  # preprocess image to make it easier to ocr
  image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>% 
  image_deskew() %>% 
  image_resize("2000x") %>% 
  ocr()

df <- data.table::fread(text = input)
#> Warning in data.table::fread(text = input): Detected 11 column names but the
#> data has 12 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 1 extra default column name for
#> the first column which is guessed to be row names or an index. Use setnames()
#> afterwards if this guess is not correct, or fix the file write command that
#> created the file to create a valid file.
df
#>     V1     info    tmax ACREAGE                               GLOBALID
#>  1:  1 PRISM_tm 30.3976  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>  2:  2 PRISM_tm 26.0226  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>  3:  3 PRISM_tm 27.1775  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>  4:  4 PRISM_tm  24,164  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>  5:  5 PRISM_tm  24.458  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>  6:  6 PRISM_tm  26.118  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>  7:  7 PRISM_tm  27.259  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>  8:  8 PRISM_tm  30.105  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>  9:  9 PRISM_tm  30.697  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 10: 10 PRISM_tm   32949  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 11: 11 PRISM_tm  32,966  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 12: 12 PRISM_tm  32.081  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 13: 13 PRISM_tm  29.847  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 14: 14 PRISM_tm  27.576  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 15: 15 PRISM_tm  24.671  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 16: 16 PRISM_tm  24.382  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 17: 17 PRISM_tm  24.382  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 18: 18 PRISM_tm  26.365  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 19: 19 PRISM_tm  29.246  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 20: 20 PRISM_tm  30.737  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 21: 21 PRISM_tm  31.658  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 22: 22 PRISM_tm  31.386  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 23: 23 PRISM_tm   32457  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 24: 24 PRISM_tm  32.093  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 25: 25 PRISM_tm  30.303  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 26: 26 PRISM_tm  26.231  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#> 27: 27 PRISM_tm  25.956  783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D}
#>     V1     info    tmax ACREAGE                               GLOBALID
#>     datasource variable    datatype resolutior    Date year month
#>  1:      PRISM     tmax provisional      4kmM3 2021-10 2021    10
#>  2:      PRISM     tmax provisional      4kmM3 2021-11 2021    11
#>  3:      PRISM     tmax provisional      4kmM3 2021-12 2021    12
#>  4:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-01 2005     1
#>  5:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-02 2005     2
#>  6:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-03 2005     3
#>  7:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-04 2005     4
#>  8:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-05 2005     5
#>  9:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-06 2005     6
#> 10:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-07 2005     7
#> 11:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-08 2005     8
#> 12:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-09 2005     9
#> 13:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-10 2005    10
#> 14:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-11 2005    11
#> 15:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2005-12 2005    12
#> 16:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-01 2006     1
#> 17:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-02 2006     2
#> 18:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-03 2006     3
#> 19:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-04 2006     4
#> 20:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-05 2006     5
#> 21:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-06 2006     6
#> 22:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-07 2006     7
#> 23:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-08 2006     8
#> 24:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-09 2006     9
#> 25:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-10 2006    10
#> 26:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-11 2006    11
#> 27:      PRISM     tmax      stable      4kmM3 2006-12 2006    12
#>     datasource variable    datatype resolutior    Date year month
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The warning from `fread` can be safely ignored as it only complains about the missing header in the first column.

Comment: That is a very interesting solution, @JBGruber! Unfortunately, in my case, I get: `Warning message:
In data.table::fread(text = input) :
  Stopped early on line 5. Expected 12 fields but found 13. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<4 PRISM_tm 24.164 783805 {257865E5-DA82-41F8-B679-169C60B2BB4D} PRISM tmax stable 4kmM3 =. 2005-01 2005 1>>`

Comment: That's very odd. Did you run this exact code? Maybe you are using a different version of ImageMagick?

Comment: Thanks for answering, @JBGruber. Indeed, I am using a different version of  ImageMagick: 6.9.12.32. Maybe, this is the reason.

Comment: I think that version is from 2017. I'm not quite sure how to update it. What OS are you on?

Comment: Thanks again, @JBGruber: I am using Fedora Linux 36.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the Fedora package manager but I believe it should have a more recent version. Maybe check https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Comment: You might also consider updating `tesseract`: `sudo yum install tesseract-devel leptonica-devel`. I'm running version 5.2.0. You can check with `tesseract::tesseract_info()`.

Comment: Thanks, @JBGruber: I am running tesseract 5.0.1 -- also too old.